# Develop Google Chrome Plugin (no Extensions !)

Tags: api, google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-extension, ria

I want to develop an RIA and I need to handle some computer hardware not already supported.
So, I think first to use a Java applet but I change my choice and I prefer the way to develop plugins for web browsers.
I began to search for a Chrome API to develop plugins like Flash Player (before being integrated in chrome) and all I found was to develop "Extensions" with HTML and Javascript...not really what I wanted !
So if you know where I can get the Chrome API, I would really appreciate ! 
Thanks by advance and sorry for my poor English ( ask me if you don't really understand my answer )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct in assuming that the best way to handle unsupported hardware *in the browser* is a plugin; but you might find that a desktop application is better for this purpose.

Flash Player and other plugins use the [**Netscape Plugin API** (NPAPI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) in Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc, and [ActiveX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX) in Internet Explorer.  The best place to start with NPAPI is actually the [Plugins page on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Plugins).  Google also has some [documentation on plugins specific to Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi).

If you are interested in developing plugins specifically for Chrome, it's worth noting that Google have developed a new API called the "Pepper Plugin API", and Adobe have announced that Flash will be moving to this API at some point.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer !!! Just an additional question : Why is it better to use a desktop application ? Netscape Plugin would have some gaps ? and I don't know if I'm right but I find it a little ungrateful to launch another software to use a RIA ? Thank you again you're my god !!!

Comment: I would recommend a desktop application only because they are generally better understood.  You can create a desktop app which embeds a web browser component to take advantage of your existing RIA platform.  If you create a plugin, you have to deal with the same problems as a desktop application - installation, platform compatibility, updates etc, plus the additional limits and unique properties of the NPAPI - such as the security implications and the plugin being unloaded when the tab/browser is closed.  At the end of the day, either will work, so you can choose what works best for you.